# only one popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

The issue is that i only one popup on the map is dispalyed.
I can see all the points but popup can see only on the last point of the list.

I'm stack with rhis problem from Sunday and can not find any info that could solve my problem on the internet :(

```
    // create the layer
                                        var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Venues");

                                        // Define markers as "features" of the vector layer:
var feature = [];    



for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                                feature[i] = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                                new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(value.location.lng, value.location.lat).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), {
                                    description: "Name: " + Name + "<br>Address:" + value.location.address + "<br>Likes: " + value.likes.count + "<br>Here now: " + value.hereNow.count
                                }, {
                                    fillColor: '#008040',
                                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                                    strokeColor: "#ee9900",
                                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                                    strokeWidth: 1,
                                    pointRadius: 8
                                }

                                );

                                vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature); 

                                map.addLayer(vectorLayer);


                                //Add a selector control to the vectorLayer with popup functions
                                var controls = {
                                    selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
                                        onSelect: createPopup,
                                        onUnselect: destroyPopup
                                    })
                                };

                                function createPopup(feature) {
                                    feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
                                    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                                    null,
                                        '<div class="markerContent">' + feature.attributes.description + '</div>',
                                    null,
                                    true,

                                    function() {
                                        controls['selector'].unselectAll();
                                    });
                                    //feature.popup.closeOnMove = true;
                                    map.addPopup(feature.popup);
                                }

                                function destroyPopup(feature) {
                                    feature.popup.destroy();
                                    feature.popup = null;
                                }


                                map.addControl(controls['selector']);
                                controls['selector'].activate();

                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that when i run my code in

- Google Chrome - i can see all the points but only one popup
- Firefox - one point no popup
- IE - can see all the points and all popups